# how to Zoom to max extent in openlayers3?

Tags: javascript, openlayers

How to zoom to max extent on click of button in openlayers-3?

I tried with

```
function zoomtoextent(){
//map.zoomToMaxExtent(); 
if(globalbBox==null)
    {
    var bBox = new OpenLayers.Bounds(
           68.14806781208101, 20.118149140613397,
        74.47891169978561, 24.722655175866358
    );
    map.zoomToExtent(bBox);
    map.zoomTo("7");
    globalbBox = bBox;

    }
else
    {
        map.zoomToExtent(globalbBox);
    }
}
```

This was working fine with openlayers-2 but with openlayers-3 it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OpenLayer.Bounds` doesn't exist anymore.

Currently you can do (if your map use EPSG:4326):

```
function zoomtoextent() {
  map.getView().fit([68, 20, 74, 24]);
}
```

See [api](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.9.0/apidoc/ol.View.html#fit)